# constructing a Queue linked list using only one head pointer

Tags: python

I'm trying to construct a Queue linked list using only a head pointer (no tail).
but i cant seem to enqueue at the end of the list.

example: at the moment the code will: `c -> b -> a`, however i would like reverse it `a -> b -> c`.

```
class Node:
    '''A node for a linked list.'''

    def __init__(self, initdata):
        self.data = initdata
        self.next = None

class Queue(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None

    def enqueue(self, item):
        """Add an item onto the tail of the queue."""
        if self.head == None:
            temp = Node(item)
            temp.next = self.head
            self.head = temp
        else:
            current = self.head
            while current != None:
                current = current.next
            if current == None:
                temp = Node(item)
                temp.next = current
                current = temp

    def dequeue(self):
        if self.head == None:
            raise IndexError("Can't dequeue from empty queue.")
        else:
            current_first = self.head
            current = self.head.next
            return current_first.data
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it:

```
class Node:
    '''A node for a linked list.'''
    def __init__(self, initdata):
        self.data = initdata
        self.next = None

class Queue(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None

    def enqueue(self, item):
        """Add an item onto the tail of the queue."""
        if self.head is None:
            self.head = Node(item)
        else:
            current = self.head
            while current.next is not None:
                current = current.next
            current.next = Node(item)

    def dequeue(self):
        if self.head is None:
            raise IndexError("Can't dequeue from empty queue.")
        else:
            first = self.head
            self.head = self.head.next
            return first.data
```

Besides some logic fixes (we need to create a new node and store it in `current.next`, `current` is just a variable pointing to a node), note we use `is` operator for testing for `None` and `Node` constructor to set data (so we can create and assign new nodes without `temp` var).

For example:

```
q = Queue()
q.enqueue('a')
q.enqueue('b')
q.enqueue('c')

print(q.dequeue())
print(q.dequeue())
print(q.dequeue())
```

Outputs:

```
a
b
c
```

Btw, note that such structure requires `O(N)` insertion time and `O(1)` deletion (pop) time. Double-ended queue (like the standard [`collections.deque`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.deque)) will do both insertion and deletion in constant time.